# How do I assign connect role to a user created in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have created a new user in mysql and would like to assign "connect" role to this user.  After that I would like to grant only select and insert privilege.  I did quite search but couldn't find any reliable answer that would tell me how to do it.
I don't want to do

```
  grant all on testdb.* to user1 ;
```

Or

```
   grant *.* on testdb to user 1 ;
```

Is there any other way I could assign only connect role and then select,insert privilege ?  Thank you and I appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do but take a look here, it has all the info you need  [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough earlier.  I would like to have user connect to database and then only have "Select" and "Insert" privilege.  No other privilege at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE USER 'someuser'@'somehost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass'; 
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```